# Какая команда позволит в Linux удалить имеющийся файл?

Tags: linux, bash

Подключена к удаленному серверу по ssh через PuTTy. Надо удалить файл week. Чего писать в командной строке что бы его удалить?

А что бы папку удалить надо будет другую команду писать или точно такую же как для удаления файла?

Comment: [rm](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=rm&category=1&russian=0)

Comment: rm <файл> или rm -r <папка>

Comment: Просмотрев два твоих вопроса понял что ты интересуешся терминальными командами UNIX/Linux. Так и гугли. Какие есть терминальные команды, а также научись пользоваться man в терминале, это очень поможет

Comment: @L.F.C. 
1) Я не знала что всё это называется терминальными командами Linux. 
2) буду гуглить что такое man. 
3) я просто учусь работать с удаленной базой. И мне посоветовали поучится сначала обращаться к ней через putty. Что потом проще будет понять как все это работает и потом пойду в DataGrip

Comment: @Marika, главное не удалите базу) Для редактирования вопроса нужно нажать "править" под ним. Но я его уже более-менее поправил. Я бы посоветовал посмотреть курс [Введение в Linux](https://stepik.org/course/73/syllabus), там как раз основы работы с Linux в командной строке, в том числе с удаленным сервером.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102283/discussion-on-question-by-marika-----linux--).

Comment: @Marika начните, например, с https://habr.com/ru/post/267825/

Answer (score 6):

Как уже написали коллеги в комментариях:

```sh
$ rm file.txt
$ rm -r dir
```

Если директория `dir` не пуста, то понадобится ещё ключ
`-f`.  Но будьте осторожны, это крайне жестокая команда.
Никакой «корзины» в Unix-системах нет, файлы удаляются сразу
безвозвратно.

Comment: ключик `-f` нужен чтобы не было вопросов при удалении защищённых от записи файлов и ругани, если файл, указанный в аргументах, уже удалён... к тому, содержит ли что-то директория или нет он отношения не имеет — проглотит и не подавится... и ещё стоило бы упомянуть `rmdir` для удаления только пустых каталогов... ЗЫ: а ещё, по одной старой доброй традиции людей, которые называют каталоги «папками» принято закидывать тухлыми овощами...

Comment: @Fat-Zer "людей, которые называют каталоги «папками» принято закидывать тухлыми овощами" - какой ужас)) буду иметь ввиду... ну или ходить в резиновых сапогах и длинном плаще резиновом

Comment: @Marika, это неправда. Никто вас не будет закидывать, так делают лишь неустоявшиеся психически индивиды :) (Это у него юмор такой)